# Android Studio 3.2 menu and text became unreadable

Tags: android-studio

Anyone encountered this problem after updating to Android Studio 3.2? I have been looking for a fix the past couple days. Uninstall and reinstall does not fix it. My only option is probably downgrading to 3.1
[image: picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it's actually material theme that's acting up since Windows 10 October Update 
https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains/issues/957